Will Spirit trade with SAVEQ when it recovers?
Let’s say I bought a share today of SAVEQ stock at 15 cents. SAVEQ is the Spirit symbol after being delisted.
Assuming Spirit recovers, is re-listed at NYSE, and the price goes up to $1, does that mean that the share I bought for 0.15 is now worth $1?

This is from their press release: pirit Airlines Announces Comprehensive Agreement to Deleverage Balance Sheet and Position the Company for Long-Term Success as a Leading Low-Fare Carrier

As a result of the chapter 11 filing, Spirit expects to be delisted
from the New York Stock Exchange in the near term. The Company expects
that its common stock will continue to trade in the over-the-counter
marketplace through the chapter 11 process. The shares are expected to
be cancelled and have no value as part of Spirit's restructuring.

It becomes a game of hot potato. If somebody buys your shares great. but if they don't and you own shares at the end of this process they will be worthless.
This is from FINRA: What a Corporate Bankruptcy Means for Shareholders

Trading After Bankruptcy: A High-Risk Gamble
Companies that file for Chapter 11 bankruptcy protection often fail to
meet the listing requirements of the major exchanges—and are
subsequently delisted. Still, they may continue to trade
over-the-counter. Bankrupt companies typically have the letter "Q"
appended to the end of their stock symbols to denote the bankruptcy.
Investors may also operate under the false assumption that once a
company has emerged from bankruptcy, their old stocks will regain
value. In fact, the opposite is most often true: most reorganization
plans, once put into effect, cancel existing shares. Only "new"
shares—those issued by the reorganized company under a new trading
symbol—have value.
Investors should understand that buying common stock of companies in
Chapter 11 bankruptcy is extremely risky and can lead to financial
loss.

Expect to lose all your money when you buy shares of a company in this situation.

Thanks for the post.
So generally speaking, a delisted company that’s later readded to the NYSE will automatically trade under a new symbol?

If they comeback from Chapter 11, they are almost 100% to be a different company with a similar name,  The old stock will be worthless. They can be delisted for many reasons, but this is a bankrupt company that has been delisted.

If you are comparing the Spirit / SAVEQ bankruptcy with the American Airlines bankruptcy from 2011, this 2013 Reuters article has some useful details: https://www.reuters.com/article/business/amr-shareholders-to-receive-rare-value-from-chapter-11-idUSL1N0BF0T0/

It is essential to be certain that you understand the situation correctly if you want to make a successful investment. And there are many, many things to misunderstand. Chapter 11 allows protection for a company to reorganize — which is not what "bankrupt" means to most people — or Webster's dictionary. De-listing the stock only means the shares trade on the over-the-counter market (OTC, or "pink sheets") which has lower standards than the major exchanges. Investopedia has a decent article about the OTC market.

It's common for companies that emerge from bankruptcy to trade stock again using the same ticker that they did before, but the stock does not transfer with the ticker. The stock in the old company becomes worthless and a new set of stock is issued that trades under the same ticker is issued.
So no, your $0.15 stock will not be worth $1 after bankruptcy. It will be worthless.
